# Regenerative Braking of DC motor

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, motors, regenerative-braking

I'm looking to implement a simple regenerative braking circuit in order to measure how much energy could be regenerated using a DC motor. My knowledge of electronics is very basic to say the least so I was looking for a bit of help.

I'm looking to power the motor until it reaches it maximum velocity. I'll measure the input voltage and current using a daq device across the resistor R2 in the diagram In order to energy the input power and energy.

Then using a double pole double throw switch i'm going to connect the motor to these capacitors to store the generated emf from the motor whilst measuring the generated voltage and current across R2.

Would this work? Apologies if this problem is of a trivial nature for this forum, like I said, my knowledge of electronics is pretty basic.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

what I would do instead is omit the capacitors and immerse the load resistor R1 in a small, well-insulated container of water with a thermocouple in it. regardless of the nature of the waveform being generated by the motor while it is being used as a brake, the temperature rise of the water will furnish an accurate accounting of the energy being dumped by the motor, as long as the resistance of the motor is small compared to the load resistance.